# Adding AWS.Logging.NLog to existing loggers in .Net Core 6 when building the host

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

I have an existing "Logging" section on my appsettings.json that writes to a rolling local file. But I'd like to add AWS logging as well.

I am used to code like this to add another NLog target, but I haven't a clue how to do this with AWS.Logging.NLog

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .UseSystemd()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((w, c) =>
        {
            c.AddCustomJsonFile("app.config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            // allow for custom overrides for this specific config (this is handled already for appsettings.json)
            if (w.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName != Environments.Production)
            {
                c.AddCustomJsonFile($"app.config.{w.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
             }
           }).ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logBuilder) =>
           {
               // REMOVE THIS CODE BELOW AND ADD AWS Logging...
               //
               // If we are configured to additionally use NLog, added it to the logging configuration
               //
               if (hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging:NLog").Exists()) {
               logBuilder.AddNLog(
                    new NLogLoggingConfiguration(
                                hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging:NLog")
                    )
                ).SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### NEWEST

Add `AWS.Logger.SeriLog` NuGet package in your project.

For more details, please check this blog.

[How To Write Logs To Amazon CloudWatch Using Serilog In .NET 6 Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-write-logs-to-amazon-cloudwatch-using-serilog-in-net-6-web-api/)

---

#### PREVIOUS

It seems you still use the previous structre in .net 6 project.

> Adding Amazon CloudWatch as a logging provider is easily done by calling the AddAWSProvider extension method of the ILoggingBuilder as shown below.

[Using .NET Logging Providers](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/amazon-cloudwatch-logs/#using-net-logging-providers)

Comment: Helpful, but I need to add this as an additional logger. Also, builder.Logging is not available as in the example (of course this might be a result of using the pre .netcore 6 HostBuilder)